# Firebase FCM protocols

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the protocol used by FCM when receiving a message using ***Topic Messaging***? The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall) does not reference any protocol details involved in Topic Messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it uses gRPC protocol to devices.

Answer (score 0):

The wire protocols that Firebase Cloud Messaging uses to deliver messages are not documented. Receiving messages is only supported by using a Firebase SDK. For example, see the documentation on how to [handle messages sent to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).

Comment: I understand how to handle the messages, the question is that what protocol do devices use? HTTP/2 or XMPP?